# Implementing ApplicationOAuthProvider in api controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I have a requirement in web api to implement the login method in api controller.I am using identity 2.0 in web api.Is there any way to implement ApplicationOAuthProvider inside an api controller class.

```
 public class LoginController : ApiController 
{
  // implement identity login here
}
```

Comment: owin is a good  middleware , I had read a good article implementing this (token based authentication in particular) http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/